# Animation function and toggle button

Tags: jquery

I have a button and a div container that I want to hide if it overflows the page.

With that button I want to animate from right to left and from left to right the div movement.

Something like:

But something is not right.

html css :

```
.animate({marginleft: -300px})
```

and the reverse

```
.animate({marginleft: 0px})
```

Code below :

```
<div id="call"></div>
<div id="wrapper-buttons"></div>

<style>
#call{
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
#wrapper-buttons{
float:right;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
color: red;
margin-right:-300px;
}
</style>

$(function() {

  $("#call").toggle(function() {       
      $('#wrapper-buttons').animate({ left: '0' }, 500);

  }, function() {       
      $('#wrapper-buttons').animate({ left: '-300' }, 500);

  });
});
```

Comment: Could you add some of the code which defines this button now? Questions like this can be difficult to answer without your existing code as a starting point.

Comment: Hello Kenster, i have updated below

Comment: What do you mean with: But something is not right. What is happening? When I put it in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e220Lnez/ There is animating something.

Comment: Yes, but i want that animation to be when I click the button, not when the page is loading

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/e220Lnez/1/ ? I placed the trigger in a on button click event.

Comment: Yes but this will fadeout the entire div and hide it

Comment: I just want to move the div not to hide it

Comment: Than don't use toggle. Toggle shows or hide the div. You can detect th button click and that run an if statement what checks the button's position and than animates the right things.

Answer (score 0):

I have resesarched and the answer is :

HTML :

```
<div id="slidemarginleft" class="slide">
  <button>slide it</button>
  <div class="inner" style="margin-left: 0px;">Animate this element's margin-left style property</div>
</div>

Css : 

.slide {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 120px;
width: 350px;
margin: 1em 0;
background-color: #ffc;
border: 1px solid #999;
}

.slide .inner {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 338px;
height: 36px;
padding: 6px;
background-color: #4c5;
color: #333;
}

.slide button {
margin: .7em 0 0 .7em;
}
```

jQuery :

```
$('#slidemarginleft button').click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
    $marginLefty.animate({
      marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
```